# Why is my Assert failing - expected 'x' but found 'x'?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

Why is my Assert failing - expected 'x' but found 'x'?

My data table:

```
Examples: 
        |              url                          |   username   |    password        |message|
        |       http://www.example.com  |   user1      |    pass1           |validation failed|
        |       http://www.example.com  |   webdriver  |    webdriver123    |validation succeeded|
```

My code which uses the assertion:

```
@Then("^the user should be presented with the following prompt alert \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_user_should_be_presented_with_the_following_prompt_alert(String message) throws Throwable {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println("DEVIL:" + alert.getText());
    Assert.assertSame(message.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s",""), alert.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Failure:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected same:<validationsucceeded> was not:<validationsucceeded>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotSame(Assert.java:828)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:771)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:782)
```

[image]

Comment: `assertSame` compares identity instead of value. Does changing this to `assertEquals` fix the problem?

Comment: @jsheeran im afraid its the sane case :[

Comment: [mcve] would be useful. I bet that if you start removing things like selenium and cucumber to convert it into plain unit test, you will easily spot where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals()`

You used `org.junit.Assert.assertSame()` which compares if one object refers to the same object. And in your case, you use `toLowerCase()` method, which results to `new String`. So, you compare two different objects. And when test fails, it outputs to console `toString()` value of object, that's why you got expected which is the same with actual.

Below example reproduce your case, and this fails with error: `expected same:<text> was not:<text>`

```
String obj = "TEXT";
String obj2 = "text";
Assert.assertSame(obj.toLowerCase(), obj2.toLowerCase());
```

And below, is what you're looking for, it will pass successfully

```
String obj = "TEXT";
String obj2 = "text";
Assert.assertEquals(obj.toLowerCase(), obj2.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `assertEquals` that checks if both of inputs are equal (based on comparison with `isEqual()`.

   ```
   import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

   String message1 = message.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","")
   String message2 = alert.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","")
   assertEquals(message1, message2);
   ```
2. The important note: Please never store raw passwords anywhere. Use their hashes ideally with salt.